# Solace VPN and username keys for REST Request

Tags: javascript, rest, messaging, solace

I am testing REST based request.
Here is the snippet from the node http request sample.

```
var requestTxt = 'test';

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Length': requestTxt.length,
    'Solace-Reply-Wait-Time-In-ms': 30000
}   

reqOptions{
    host: '10.28.112.100',
    port: 9000,
    path: '/tutorial/requests',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers
}
```

The above options and headers works for VMR with default VPN and username.
Now I have a VPN setup with username. Anybody know how and where we can specify VPN and username info in an REST/HTTP request ?

I followed the javascript example and tried the keys below for REST request but no luck :

```
reqOptions{
    host: '10.28.112.100',
    port: 9000,
    path: '/tutorial/requests',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers

    vpnName: 'TEST_VPN_2',
    username: 'user'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTTP Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) header to specify the username/password.
A “username:password’ is encoded into a single base64 string, which spans the “:”.

Here is an example for user Aladdin, password OpenSesame:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

You can refer to the complete list of HTTP headers over [here](https://sftp.solacesystems.com/Portal_Docs/#page/REST_Messaging_Protocol_Guide/2_Solace_REST_Message_Encoding.html#).